# How to convert a Buffer object to a file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I'm developing a web application using (MySQL)EAN stack. I saved png/jpg/pdf as BLOB in MySQL. Now, I can retrieve them as Buffer objects in Node.js by using [Sequelize.js](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/#one-to-one-associations):

```
exports.loadUploadedFiles = function(req, res) {
    db.File.findAll().success(function(files) {
       //res.send(files[0].dataValues.data.toString('ascii')); // I have tried to convert a Buffer to ascii and sent it to Angular.js, however, I still don't know how to transform them to a file link.
       res.send(files); // How can I return the Buffer objects to Angular.js
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
};
```

I have tried two approaches:

- Return the Buffer objects to Angular.js, then, find a way to generate downloadable links from them.
- Convert the Buffer objects to ascii by using bufferObject.toString('ascii'), then, find a way to transform these ascii to downloadable links

I have been trying for a day and still can't figure it out in both approaches :( , any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think #1 is the best option.
Dumping the Buffer to a file on the file system in a publicly accessible directory is likely the best bet.

[FileSystem Write in Node](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback)

Comment: The way to generate the links will depend on what framework you are using to host the site.

Comment: I think it would be better to generate downloadable links directly from the Buffer without creating files on the file system. If not, it would have a lot of files on the file system and I have to manually delete them when not needed.